# ajax submitting more than one variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just started with jquery and ajax and have one simple question I guess:

I have a button on my html page like this:

```
<button type="button" id="i" id2="id2" name="name" class="button_red">-</button>
```

I implement this JavaScript code for a GET-Method with ajax:

```
$('button').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "update_data.php",
    data:  // data here
  });
});
```

All I want is to send all variables from the button (like id, id2, name, class) with the ajax method to my update_data.php file. How do I do that in the best way? And how do I use then .serialize()?

My idea was like:

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var id2 = $(this).attr('id2');
var name = $(this).attr('name');
var array = {id, id2, name};
//
//
//
data: array, array.serialize(),
succcess: ...
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to SO. First step, sort your indentation out. It's a good habit to cement - makes things much more easier (also helps us to help). Secondly, `data` is easiest and most readable/editable when it's an object, so I'd recommend building an object of data then feeding it to `data`.

Comment: In javascript, it will be ``JSON.stringify()``  not **serialize()**.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery AJAX documentation: https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/

---

You can send this either

1) as an `object`

```
var DTO = {
  id: $(this).attr('id'),
  id2: $(this).attr('id2'),
  name: $(this).attr('name')
};
```

2) as an `array`

```
var DTO = [
    $(this).attr('id'),  
  $(this).attr('id2'),
  $(this).attr('name')
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that returns all attributes of a given jQuery node as an object:

```
function getAttributes ( $el ) {
    var attributes = {};
    $.each( $el[0].attributes, function () {
        attributes[this.name] = this.value;
    });

  return attributes;
}
```

and then use it in your `click` handler:

```
$('button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
        url: "update_data.php",
        data:  getAttributes( $(this) )  // get all Attributes of the button
    });
});

// getAttributes( $(this) ) returns:
{
  class: "button_red",
  id: "i",
  id2: "id2",
  name: "name",
  type: "button"
}
```

The advatage is that you can easily reuse that anywhere you need no matter how many / complex the attributes on your elements get, the disadvatage is that you dont have full control over the data, as you might have noticed, the `class` and `type` attributes are added which you did not specify - it just returns all of them.